# replace default camera windows phone 8.1

Tags: camera, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

Im working on a camera App and need to replace the default WinRT 8.1 camera app with my own. Is there a simple way to set my app as a default camera?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there is a way to change the default camera app since WP8 GDR2 update, only special developers (or only OEMs?) are allowed to register their apps to show up in the selection. Nokia is the only manufacturer that uses that with their own Nokia camera apps.

Comment: Nothing changed since then?